# InstallShield 2014 - Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installshield

I am stuck with InstallShield 2014 for this project (InstallShield want too much money to upgrade their product and not enough time to convert to WiX or something else) with Visual Studio 2015 and with that, the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Package (x86)".  I copied the prerequisite settings from the 2012 entry in IS and updated the values for 2015.  Problem is it does not always work.  I checked on Windows 7 64 Bit and on there the registry with the minumal version installed is in the Wow6432Node.  However, in Windows Server 2012 64 Bit they just dump it in the regular registry node.

So on 2012 64:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VC\Servicing\14.0\RuntimeMinimum

But on 7 64:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\VC\Servicing\14.0\RuntimeMinimum

I was wondering if anyone has a solution for this or if you happen to have IS 2015 Update 1 where they supposedly fixed this, copying the details of the prerequisite properties.  I even signed up for a InstallShield trial, but they give you 2015, not the 2015 update 1.  IS 2015 does not even know about the prerequisite for Visual C++ 2015 yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I made a mistake. :-(  I was comparing my development machine with a VM where I had installed the redistributable.  Seems when you download the Visual C++ 2015 redistributable you get an older version of the package.  If you look at what's installed with the latest update of Visual Studio 2015 it's a newer version.

So once you figure that out, the way to check then is to use the Uninstall registry entry with the correct GUID.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{23DAF363-3020-4059-B3AE-DC4AD39FED19} is what you need for the latest version of the package.

Unfortunately InstallShield of course want you to always pay the maintenance fee, so their support forums are closed.  So unless you pay that, you don't get much updated information.

For those who are interested, this is the URL used to download the prq package from the InstallShield servers.  This gives you a good starting package to work with, you then just have to update the GUID to that above and update the install package locally to the newest version.
http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Package (x86).prq

And there you have it!  Bob's your uncle.  Have a great day and hopefully you never need this information. :-)

Comment: My version (14.0.23824) had a different uninstall GUID of {F899BAD3-98ED-308E-A905-56B5338963FF}, so altering it didn't work.  However, the original GUID in that file matches the Uninstall entry created by the vcredist file the prq tries to download.  So I think the more reliable route is to just use the prq file as-is.